# how to write soql query to fetch records <=1000 etc

Tags: apex, soql

Hai iam new to salesforce i need to write the query depending on the values entered by the user i.e, when a user enters the value 10,000 i need to display the all the record  values <=10,000. how can I get this with the following code?

This is my controller code

```
public with sharing class  SearchapplicantsController {   

    private String soql {get;set;}
    // the collection of contacts to display
      Public List<Applicant__c> applicants {get;set;}
    // the current sort direction. deaults to asc
      public String sortDir{
      get { if (sortDir == null) { sortDir = 'asc'; } 
             return sortDir;
             }
             set;
             }
    // the current field to sort by. defaults to last name 
        public String sortField {
          get {
                if  ( sortField == null) {
                sortField = 'Last_Name__c'; } return sortField; }
                set;
                }
      // format the soql for display on the visualforce page 
           public String debugSoql {
              get { return soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + 'limit 20 '; }
               set;
               }
      // init the contrller and display some sample data when the page loads
          public SearchapplicantsController() {
            soql='select First_name__c,Last_name__c,Skill_set__c,Experience__C,Expected_Annual_Salary__c,Location__c,Qualification__c from  Applicant__c  where Candidate__c.First_name__c != null';    
                   runQuery();
                   }
        // toggles the sorting  of query from asc<-->desc
            public void toggleSort() {
              //simply toggle the direction  
                   sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc' ;
                  // run the query again
                    runQuery();
                    }             
        //runs the actualquery
           public void runQuery() {
              try {
                   applicants = Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 20 ');
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                     ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ' OOOps! ') );
                     }
                   }                                
   // runs the search with parameters passed via JavaScript
   public PageReference runSearch(){

   /* SNIP */

    soql='select First_name__c,Last_name__c,Skill_set__c,Experience__c,Expected_Annual_Salary__c,Location__c,Qualification__c from Applicant__c where Applicant__c.First_name__c != null' ;    

   /* SNIP */


    if (!Qualification.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Qualification__c LIKE (\''+Qualification+'\')';

    // run the query again
    runQuery();

    return null;
  }
}
```

Is there any code snippet please provide..........

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the input from the user using an input field:

`<apex:inputText value="{!TheLimit}"/>`

Which is tied to a public property in the controller (you'll need to input validation in JS, or use a string and do it in the controller):

```
public Integer TheLimit {get; set;}
```

And then just use the value in a comparison expression in your SOQL:

```
soql += ' where Salary__c <= : TheLimit ';
```

*Side note*

For future questions, please try to reduce the amount of extraneous code posted, only include what's needed to explain the question.

Comment: or if the intention is to return rows below a limiting value (rather than limit to a specific number of rows) then something like soql += ' and expected_annual_salary__c < ' TheLimit

Comment: hai DougB ............ you suggested this to write in the code  soql += ' and expected_annual_salary__c < ' TheLimit   Is there any way of changing my above code to get all the values of  salary <= the value enterd .Any code snipet please provide me...